# Scanning Elements of A Matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I need to write a code that scan a matrix from the most left and down element to the right moving with diagonals.

For example for the matrix [1 2 3; 4 5 6] it should return 4,5,1,6,2,3

Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? The scanning order confuses me, and the example is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show your attempts, I'll let you figure out how this code works :-)

```
x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
m = bsxfun(@minus, (1:size(x,1)).', 1:size(x,2));
[~, ind] = sort(reshape(m, 1, []));
result = x(flip(ind));
```

You may need to read about

- [linear indexing](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511);
- [`bsxfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [spdiags](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html)*:

```
x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
result = x(nonzeros(flipud(spdiags(reshape(1:numel(x),size(x))))));
```

*It may not be as fast as @LuisMendo's solution but it is one liner!